# Python: Calling a decorator method from another class

Tags: python, class, decorator

Let's say I have a class that defines a decorator

```
class Foo():

    def decorate(param):        
        def wrapper(func):
            def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
                # do something
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            return wrapped
        return wrapper
```

And then I decide to call that decorator in another class like so:

```
class Bar():

    foo = Foo()
    param = something

    @foo.decorate(param)
    def func():
        # do something
```

This raises a `TypeError` exception:

```
TypeError: decorate() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

I cannot understand what is going wrong here. Applying the same decorator but defined within the same class `Bar` works fine, but why does it not work over different classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply forgot to include `self`; you are calling `Foo().decorate()`, a bound method, so the instance will be passed in:

```
class Foo():
    def decorate(self, param):
```

Note that the same applies to your `Bar.func()` function:

```
class Bar():

    foo = Foo()
    param = something

    @foo.decorate(param)
    def func(self):
        # do something
```

Comment: Instantiating a `Bar` and trying to call `func` will also fail; it also needs to take `self` as a parameter.

Comment: @chucksmash: sure, but there we could reasonably assume it is incomplete sample code; the error message shows that for the decorator factory method at least the `self` was definitely forgotten.

Comment: It still does not work, I simply added self as a parameter of the decorator but it still gives me the same error.

Comment: @jablesauce: Please provide us with a [mcve] then; one that includes the *full* traceback of the exception you got. Did you make sure to *restart* Python to load the new revision of the script?

Comment: Actually my bad, I did not restart Python. I was unaware that you have to completely restart the interpreter and simply tried to re-interpret the script itself.

Answer (score 3):

Your `decorate()` function should be an instance method, and hence it accepts the instance itself as the first argument, when you call - `@foo.decorate(param)` , you are trying to pass it two arguments (since `foo` is an instance of `Foo` class) the instance itself, as well as `param` , which is causing the issue.

You should convert your `decorate()` method to accept the instance as the first argument . Example -

```
class Foo():

    def decorate(self, param):        
        def wrapper(func):
            def wrapped(*args, **kwargs):
                # do something
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            return wrapped
        return wrapper
```

---

Another thing , your `func()` is also an instance method , that also needs a `self` . Example -

```
class Bar():

    foo = Foo()
    param = something

    @foo.decorate(param)
    def func(self):
        # do something
```